# Create a texture from PointCloud in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl-3

I'm reading an article about real time rendering point clouds, and I want to implement it using opengl3.3 and c++. Article says : "First, the point set is projected into a texture".

I'm only a neophyte in OpenGL, so i'm wondering how to do so? Since it's real-time rendering, I guess we have to transform the Point Clouds we are visualising at any time into a texture. But for me, a texture is a JPG file or something like this (PPM, PGM, ... maybe), and I don't understand how is it possible to : everytime, transform the subset of point clouds we are visualizing into a JPEG (for exameple), work on this JPEG and then reinject it into OpenGL... It can't be done on real-time, right?

So, is there something I'm missing? Something include in OpenGL that can do the work and help me?

Or maybe, I create a JPEG about all the point cloud, then find the part I'm looking for using camera angle and position? Maybe that's it!

Thanks for all 
I wish you very good day.

Raphaël

Comment: AFAIK when the article says 'project into a texture', it means that the point cloud is passed to a vertex shader which transforms the points from 3D space into 2D device space. These projected points are rendered(cached) into a off screen render target (the texture). This saves on vertex processing as long as your camera perspective does not change since you can directly call the pixel shader with this buffer.

Comment: I was so absorbed by the fact that it was an insane work, that I forgot the basics. Thanks for your response. 
It is probably what they meant since this is the most basic and faster thing. 

Thanks for your help in my comprehension!